# Pytest passing arguments to fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I added an option to pass an argument in my `conftest.py` file:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--credentials',
        required=True,
        metavar='file',
        help='Path of the JSON file containing credentials',
        type=load_credentials,
        dest='credentials'
    )
```

The `load_credentials` function simply parses the passed JSON string into a JSON dataclass:

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Credentials:
    vm: UserPasswordCredentials

def load_credentials(filename: str) -> Credentials:
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            return Credentials.from_json(file.read())
    return Credentials.from_json(filename)
```

I'm trying to run the Pytest command with the `--credentials` argument with Pyvmomi like so:

```
creds = self.credentials.to_json()
creds_escaped = creds.replace('"','\\"')
cmd = 'python3 -m pytest {test_path} --credentials \'{creds_escaped}\''
```

This works fine when I'm running it from a Unix machine, however when running on a Windows machine Pytest returns exit code 4 (CLI Usage error). What am I doing wrong?